# How to handle *.framework, *.xcarchive (etc.) like the folders they are?

Tags: finder, macos

`*.framework`, `*.xcarchive` and similar are just normal folders if I look at them with command-line tools (`file`, `ls`, etc.). Still Finder treats them different from normal directories, e.g. double click opens `*.xcarchive`s with Xcode archive content viewer.

Is it somehow possible, to make Finder behave so that such folders aren't treated specially compared to any "normal" folder? Alternatively, if that is not possible, is there a file explorer, that "ignores" file extensions and just treats every file with "d"-flag as simple directory (I tried a few, but they all seem to behave like Finder)?

Comment: Do you have reasons not to right click on a bundle and select "Show Package Contents"?

Comment: Yes. E.g. being able to unfold/collapse the folder, to not lose overview in complex file-structures.

Comment: I haven’t found a direct way in years of trying, but I created an alias to be a quick entry into the bundle.  They don’t collapse or unfold either.  I’m going to try a symlink to see if that will create a mirror folder.  Another solution is to use a different file browser.  It’s easy to forget that Finder isn’t the only one, and if you’re comfortable with shell like operations, there’s a couple of good UI implementations that give powerful file system functions outside of the shell.